# How to get the body of a Retrofit Call in the callback

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

Assuming i have this dummy API

```
@POST("somepath/setSomething")
Call<ExecuteResponse> setSomething(@Body ExecuteInput input);
```

and this callBack

```
Callback<ExecuteResponse> callBack = new Callback<ExecuteResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ExecuteResponse> call, Response<ExecuteResponse> response) {};
```

How can i access the body of the call and getting back my ExecuteInput Object?

Comment: You could try `call.request()` if you are trying to get the original request.

Comment: @christoandrew that piece of code will not return me the object, but a Request object of OkHttp3

Answer (score 0):

You can do `response.getBody()` and you will get the object you specified inside `Response<???>`. In this case, `ExecuteResponse`.

Of course, I'm supposing you have defined the `@SerializedName` inside your object or that you have the right field names inside the `ExecuteResponse` model class.

Comment: i'm asking how to get the request, not the response